# Blocking custom ad dialog in webbrowser

Tags: javascript, .net, winforms, dialog, browser

I've checked other threads but are not working for me.
Following them, I've implemented this way so far:

```
  private void InjectAlertBlocker()
        {
            HtmlElement head = webBrowser4.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser4.Document.CreateElement("script");
            IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
            string alertBlocker = "window.showModalDialog = function () { };";
            alertBlocker += "window.alert = function () { };";
            alertBlocker += "getUrlParam(strParamName){};";
            alertBlocker += "getSpecialUrlsParam(strParamName) {};";
            alertBlocker += "closeButton();";

            element.text = alertBlocker;
            head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
        }
```

InjectAlertBlocker() is called from navigated and completed event..

Also I've tried:

```
   private void webBrowser_NewWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;
        if (wb != null)
            añadeTextoDebug("Un navegador quiso abrir un popup: " + wb.Url);
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Site url I want to cancel is like:
WARNING SCAM-LIKE LINK
http://cdn.adbooth.net/src/autoshortner.html?section=3605070&url=url_i_want_goes_here.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a patch/fix solution in two steps... bit hacky...

Checking the url, and if it gets redirected, the next url that we get and so on for adbooth string. ([How to programatically lengthen shortened urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474112/how-to-programatically-lengthen-shortened-urls))

Then on navigating event (just to be sure) and before navigating, in the cases I can, I trim the url like:

```
    private string noAdBooth(string lnk)
    {
        if (lnk.Contains("&url=") && lnk.Contains("adbooth"))
        {
            añadeTextoDebug("adbooth omitted");  //add txt debug
            lnk = lnk.Substring(lnk.IndexOf("&url=") + 5);
        }
        return lnk;
    }
```